# datagridview itemsource is populated but not displaying?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Only column names are showing but rows are not showing in datagridview in WPF.
I have tried putting the `autogeneratecolumns="true"` in the datagridview but getting no luck. I have debugged and checked the datatable have 2 rows but not displaying

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
    <DataGrid x:Name="GridViewProducts" Margin="80,30,0,0" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" BorderThickness="12" 
    BorderBrush="PaleTurquoise" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="200" Width="745" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: can you post xaml code and item source collection binded with ?

Comment: Looks like source is binded to grid when window is loaded and when there was no data. Can be convert the type of source to observable collection so that when its updated, grid will reflect added rows to collection

Comment: I have the same logic implemented for the other pages and those are working fine but on this page it is not displaying the rows :/

Comment: should be some difference for sure. area i suspect is when and where you load data to item source when wpf window is loaded.

Comment: It Worked thanks to you @RahulAgarwal

Comment: cool :) what was issue ?

Comment: I was clearing the datatable on loaded and somehow removing that line worked :)

Comment: ok. you might want to mark it answered to close the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably item source does not have data when window is loaded - which is why grid only shows column headers only.

Also exploring around observable collection is worth.